# Set file Type when uploading files in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

So I have the file upload working well. However I need to set type of file that is allowed, where and how do I set the type of file that can be uploaded. It's supposed to be an image file, and I don't want users (obviously) uploading anything but an image. I would assume it's somewhere in validation.yml?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways, or using the [file validation attribute](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html), or the [image validation attribute](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Image.html), this last as the accepted mime types as image/*

The examples on the site goes as followed:

```
# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    properties:
        bioFile:
            - File:
                maxSize: 1024k
                mimeTypes: [application/pdf, application/x-pdf]
                mimeTypesMessage: Please upload a valid PDF

# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author
    properties:
        headshot:
            - Image:
                minWidth: 200
                maxWidth: 400
                minHeight: 200
                maxHeight: 400
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you, I couldn't find that for the life of me. Thanks!